Can $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}{{k^{|n|}} \ln\left[ \left( \sqrt{x^2+(y+2ng)^2} \right) \right]}$ be calculated$(0<k<1)$?
Suppose there is a current array composed of countless constant currents perpendicular to the xy plane. These currents are arranged equidistant along the y-axis. The distance between adjacent currents is $2g$. The value of each current is $i$.
Schematic diagram of the first model
The vector magnetic potential generated by this current array at coordinates $(x, y)$ is  is relatively easy to calculate
$$\begin{aligned}
A(x,y) & = \frac{-\mu _0i}{2\pi} \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}{\ln \left( \sqrt{x^2+(y+2ng)^2} \right) }\\ &=\frac{-\mu _0 i}{4\pi}\left[ \ln (x^2+y^2)+\ln \left[ \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left( x^2+(y+2ng)^2 \right) \left( x^2+(y-2ng)^2 \right)} \right] \right] \end{aligned}$$
where,the key step is:
$$
\begin{aligned}
 &\ln \left[ \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left( x^2+(y+2ng)^2 \right) \left( x^2+(y-2ng)^2 \right)} \right]\\
 &=\ln \left[ \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left( \frac{x^2}{(y+2ng)^2}+1 \right) \left( \frac{x^2}{(y-2ng)^2}+1 \right) (\frac{y}{2ng}+1)^2(\frac{y}{2ng}-1)^2(2ng)^4} \right]\\
 &=\ln \left[ \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left( \frac{x^2}{(y+2ng)^2}+1 \right) \left( \frac{x^2}{(y-2ng)^2}+1 \right) (\frac{y}{2ng}+1)^2(\frac{y}{2ng}-1)^2} \right] +C\\
 &=\ln \left[ \frac{y^2\left( \sinh ^2\frac{\pi x}{2g}\cot ^2\frac{\pi y}{2g}+\cosh ^2\frac{\pi x}{2g} \right)}{x^2+y^2}\frac{4g^{2}\sin ^2\frac{\pi y}{2g}}{\pi ^2y^2} \right] +C\\
\end{aligned}
$$
Finally, we got the result
$$
\begin{aligned}
 A(x,y)&=\frac{-\mu _0 i}{4\pi}\left[ \ln\mathrm{(}x^2+y^2)+\ln \left[ \frac{y^2\left( \sinh ^2\frac{\pi x}{2g}\cot ^2\frac{\pi y}{2g}+\cosh ^2\frac{\pi x}{2g} \right)}{x^2+y^2}\frac{4g^{2}\sin ^2\frac{\pi y}{2g}}{\pi ^2y^2} \right] \right] +C\\
 &=\frac{-\mu _0 i}{4\pi}\ln \left[ \cosh \frac{\pi x}{g}-\cos \frac{\pi y}{g} \right] +C\\
\end{aligned}$$
$C$ represents a constant that is independent of $x$ and $y$. Because the constant part is not useful for calculating magnetic fields. So we use $C$ to represent them.
Obviously, the final result is very concise and elegant.
However, if the model is adjusted, the problem will become complex. Assuming that the value of the current at the origin is still $i$, while the current arrays above and below the x-axis proportionally decrease. For example, the current at $(0, \pm n \cdot 2g)$ will become $i\cdot k^n$. Where, $0<k<1$.
Schematic diagram of the second model
Now, the problem has become
$$\begin{aligned}
A(x,y)&=\frac{-\mu _0 i}{2\pi}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}{{k^{|n|}}\ln \left( \sqrt{x^2+(y+2ng)^2} \right) }\\
&=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}{\ln\left[ \left( \sqrt{x^2+(y+2ng)^2} \right) ^{k^{|n|}} \right]}\\
&=\frac{-\mu _0 i}{4\pi}\left[ \ln\mathrm{(}x^2+y^2)+\ln \left[ \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left( x^2+(y+2ng)^2 \right) ^{k^n}\left( x^2+(y-2ng)^2 \right) ^{k^n}} \right] \right]\\
\end{aligned}$$
Can this infinite series still yield concise and elegant results?

In your original setup, write $I_0$ for current through a wire, $a$ for the distance between wires. Let $B_x = A_{,y}$, $B_y = - A_{,x}$, $s=(x+\mathrm{i}y)/a$, and
$$b(s) = 2\pi a\mu_0(B_y + \mathrm{i}B_x)/I_0\text{.}$$
Put the wires through the $x$-axis. Then the original setup's solution is equivalent to
$$b(s) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{s-n} = \pi \cot \pi s$$
and your question is equivalent to asking whether the new setup's solution
$$b(s)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{k^{\lvert n\rvert}}{s-n}= s^{-1}F(1,s;s+1;k)-k(1-s)^{-1}F(1,1-s;2-s;k)$$
is also "nice". The answer, I think, must be "no": at least, unlike in the first setup, the values of the second are linearly independent over each number field for rational $s$ and some algebraic $k$. (Ideally, one would show that $b(s)$ is a nonelementary function of $s$ for fixed $k\neq 0,1$, but that seems out of reach.)

A related case that is exactly solvable arises from
$$\pi \cos(2\pi t s)\csc \pi s = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n\cos (2\pi nt)}{s-n}$$
where $-\tfrac{1}{2}\leq t\leq\tfrac{1}{2}$.
That is, the currents in the wires could vary sinusoidally.
